# How to capture the *anchor text* of a right-clicked link for a Chrome extension context menu

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, contextmenu

According to the [chrome.contextMenus api page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus) you can get linkUrl, srcUrl,  pageUrl, etc. If you select the anchor text before clicking you could use selectionText but I don't want to have to do that.

The best answer I've been able to find after much googling is [here](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-access-the-anchor-tag-value-using-onclick), which is to use document.getElementsByTagName('a') to get all the links on the page, then get the innerHTML of the one that had the url you got via linkUrl. But this would break if there were more than one link on the page to the same target url with different anchor texts.

I also found [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7427357/getting-hyperlink-text-on-chrome-right-click) to use document.activeElement but when I tried that it returned the entire body of the page, apparently right-clicking on a link does not properly make it the "active element".

Comment: Can't you use the `selection` `ContextType` since anchors' text is selected when they are right clicked ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean there, but I did try selectionText (see the Chrome developer page I linked to), and it returned an empty string unless I manually selected the link text before clicking on it, which would seem to indicate that anchor text is not actually slected just by a right click.

Comment: Beside checking the `selectionText` property of the event, did you also set the menu to appear in the `selection` context ? Something like `chrome.contextMenus.create({contexts: ["selection"]})`

Comment: I've tried it now, and it's just as before. The selectionText property doesn't even exist unless I manually select the text.